# Load google API using getScript - ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps

I am trying to load Google API dynamically using getScript() method for "Place Autocomplete Address Form". ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform )

Here's the code I came up with:

```
$.getScript( 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places', function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
    console.log( data ); // Data returned
    console.log( textStatus ); // Success
    console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
    console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

But I'm getting the following error message form my console:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google 
> undefined
> success
> 200
> Load was performed.

Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: do u have firebug installed in firefox?

Comment: no I don't, the console returns that on firefox "A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored."

Comment: I just ran your code and it was loaded successfully for me. I included jquery 1.10.1.

Comment: I tested it on a separate file from scratch, got rid of the error but returned data is still "undefined" and autocomplete not working, Under jquery 1.11.0

Answer (score 0):

Check if this fiddle helps you.. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZqqW/94/) .It loads the script dynamically and generates map.

```
.
```

Comment: Thanks, that one works fine. I tried to use the same loading method for the "places" but in vain, still the same error.

Comment: can u post your Place Autocomplete Address Form

Comment: that would be quite complicated to send extract of my own code, things are here and there to suit my navigation system and that is why I wish to load dynamically, but the whole thing does work when I hard include the google js on my main page using <script>. The complete code is under https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Comment: It does help, just not sure of what my initialise() function should look like